# HTML/CSS Why does my icons (fontawesome + IcoMoon) show up as blank squares sometimes on page load

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome-6

I have a WordPress CMS website and for all the icons (fontawesome + IcoMoon) I am not using CDN, I have these icon fonts and CSS files uploaded to the server.

Below are in the font files I have for Fontawesome 6 (I've downloaded the fontawesome package on the official site):

- fa-brands-400.ttf
- fa-brands-400.woff2
- fa-regular-400.ttf
- fa-regular-400.woff2
- fa-solid-900.ttf
- fa-solid-900.woff2
- fa-v4compatibility.ttf
- fa-v4compatibility.woff2

I am using SASS for web development, so all my custom SASS files + the fontawesome SASS files are compiled into 1 CSSfile.

I have a normalize SASS file too, so I've imported that first like this:

**style.scss file:**

`@import "normalize";`
`@import "vendors/vendors";`

**_vendors.scss file:**

`@import "fontawesome/fontawesome.scss";`
`@import "fontawesome/regular.scss";`
`@import "fontawesome/solid.scss";`
`@import "fontawesome/brands.scss";`

[image: Folder Structure]

When the webpage loads (or refreshes), it sometimes load the icons with no issue, but sometime when page reloads it will show up as blank squares. (like the screenshot below)

[image: Output]

What is the issue?

Comment: Check you browser console.